# Allow only specific package from given repo yum

Tags: yum

We have two repo A and B

Both repo provides package C

I dont want to use A for anything else , except for package C
Rest all packages i want to install from B

How to tell yum to block A for all except C package

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You should edit the `.repo` corresponding to A in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` (probably `C.repo`), and add this line :

```
includepkgs=C.*
```

And add this in `B.repo` :

```
exclude=C.*
```

It should do the trick.

Comment: A good use case for this is using DRBD from Elrepo. The kernel modules lag behind the kernel from RHEL, but the Elrepo-testing repository did have more up-to-date packages. So in this case I just needed to use 'includepkgs=*drbd90*' and 'enabled=1' to the elrepo.repo file.