# How to configure the specified repository for only one package?

Tags: opensuse, repository, software-updates

I want to change the repository for libavcodec in opensuse from tumbleweed to pacman аnd remain all other packages on the official repo after adding pacman.

Please explain how to do this?

It looks like this, but with a zipper and a yast:
[Allow only specific package from given repo yum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186886/allow-only-specific-package-from-given-repo-yum)

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that libavcodec has a few bits missing, so you want the pacman version.

- leave the openSUSE version
- install the pacman repo anyway as it has loads of useful stuff.
- remove libavcodec:

  ```
  rpm -ql libavcodec | xargs -iRR rm RR
  ```
- download (and unpack) the latest libavcodec then use

  ```
  configure --prefix=/usr
  ```
- add any missing dev packages you need for the missing bits
- repeat:

  ```
  configure --prefix=/usr
  ```
- do a

  ```
  make install
  ```

  as root

You are done.